# Angular error NG8001: 'MiComponente' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, vscode, ts

estoy dando mi primer paso en angular y ya me tira este error.
Hasta el momento lo unico que hice fue crear un nuevo componente en app, lo defini, lo declare en app.module.ts, y lo importe alli mismo.

Creo el selector
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hago la importacion del componente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error que me salta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta sería la estructura del proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cambia los \ por / en la ruta para acceder al componente.

Comment: Ya lo intente, pero sigue arrojando el mismo error :/